# boost::python argument type did not match

Tags: python, c++, boost

I export a class with a wrapper:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace {

namespace bp = boost::python;

class A {
public:
    A(){}
    virtual ~A(){}

};

struct A_Wrap:
    A, bp::wrapper<A>{

    //ctr
    A_Wrap():A(){}
    //dtr
    ~A_Wrap(){}

    //func
    void foo(){
        PySys_WriteStdout("test in");
    }
};

A* make_A(){
    return new A();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(A){

    bp::class_<A_Wrap, boost::noncopyable>("A_Wrap", bp::init<>())
        .def("foo", &A_Wrap::foo)
        ;

    bp::def("make_A", &make_A, bp::return_value_policy<bp::manage_new_object>());
}

}
```

in python:

```
import A
a = A.make_A()
a.foo()
```

results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    A_Wrap.foo(A_Wrap)
did not match C++ signature:
    foo((anonymous namespace)::A_Wrap {lvalue})
```

Im wondering why the missmatch?

I know this might look unusable, but the exact same problem arises on a similar method that is very useable to me. This is the most simplified way i reproduced the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively trying to do:

```
void foo(A_Wrap* ) { }

A* a = new A;
foo(a); // invalid conversion from A* to A_Wrap*
```

That wouldn't work in C++ either. You probably meant `make_A` to actually return an `A_Wrap`:

```
A* make_A() {
    return new A_Wrap();
}
```

That makes your code work for me:

```
>>> import A
>>> a = A.make_A()
>>> a.foo()
test in>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. What i still dont understand is why Python adresses my "A" object as a "A_Wrap" object in the first place: `print(a) -> <A.A_Wrap object at...>` although its actualy not one. Thanks.

Comment: @Bazilikum I don't know. I tried to play around with it some. `wrapper` is for `virtual`s, but you don't have any - so I don't know how it shows up as `A_Wrap`...